# How can i display a gif while a google web app loads

Tags: html, google-apps-script

well, i have a simple web app build on google apps script, i don't use html files, just code.gs.
here is a part:

```
function doGet(e) {
...............
  html += "<center><h3 style='font : bold 1.5rem Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;margin : 0 0 1em;'><a style='text-decoration : none;color : #a28351;position : relative;transition : all 0.25s linear;' href="+eventLink+" target='_blank'>" +eventTitle+"</a></h3>"+"<p style='font-size : 14px;margin : 0 0 1.5em;'>►Cuando?: "+start+"<br>►Donde?: "+location+"</br><br>"+description+"</br></p>"+
"<br/><a style='text-decoration : none;color : #a28351;position : relative;transition : all 0.25s linear;' href="+eventLink+" target='_blank'><img style='display : block;margin: 0 auto;//margin : 0 10px 10px 0;//max-width : 100%;//vertical-align: middle;//text-align: center;' src='"+eventPic+"' ></a><br/></center>";
   }
   }
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
}
```

and here is the final result: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzEBQfsg6v6176fWJOpZxAxEWVW2rCQ9lGPL1RC9KZShaCeipHN/exec

But it takes almost 7 seconds to show content and it can confound the user and make to close the window; so i want to display a gif while the code charges at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to load some minimal HTML with `doGet()`, and that code will then need to have a `window.onload` function:

```
window.onload=function() {
  console.log("window.onload ran");
};
```

So, first some code is served to the client, then the `window.onload` function automatically runs when that first HTML is loaded.  And that code, then retrieves the bulk of the HTML while the spinner is still spinning.

Inside the `window.onload` function, cause the spinner to start working by injecting some HTML into a DIV element:

```
<div> this is a test</div>
<div id='divSpinner'></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload=function() {
    console.log("This onload did run");
    //Start Spinner however you wish
    window.startSpinner();//Call function to start spinner
  };

  window.startSpinner = function(){
    //Code to start spinner
    //Search internet for ways to display a spinner
  };
</script>
```

The `window.onload` function runs the `google.script.run` API and gets the rest of the HTML content, injects it into the page, and then finally shuts down the spinner.

This is the full code:

### HTML for start up:

```
<div id='idMainContent'> this is a test</div>
<div id='divSpinner'></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload=function() {
    console.log("This onload did run");

    //Start Spinner however you wish
    window.startSpinner();//Call function to start spinner

    google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onFailure)
      .withSuccessHandler(injectMyContent)
      .getMainContent();

  };

  window.startSpinner = function(){
    //Code to start spinner
    //Search internet for ways to display a spinner
  };

window.injectMyContent = function(argHTML) {
  document.getElementById('idMainContent').innerHTML = argHTML;

  //Clear spinner DIV
  document.getElementById('divSpinner').innerHTML = "";
  //Hide spinner
  document.getElementById('divSpinner').style.display = 'none';

};
</script>
```

### Code.gs

```
function doGet() {

  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('test HTML')
    .setTitle('The Name of Your Page')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
};

function getMainContent() {
  return "<div>This is new HTML!</div>";
};
```

If you want to do this without getting HTML from a file, you can certainly do that, my example shows getting the initial HTML from a file.  I've tested this, and it works.  It first shows a spinner and some minimal msg, then more content is retrieved from the server, and injected into the site.

Comment: i want to add that besides this, the most important part is that you set the sandbox mode to iframe or native. If its using emulated mode you wont be able to show anything until the environment loads which does take about 7 sec.

Comment: The NATIVE and EMULATED sandbox modes were deprecated on October 13, 2015 and both are now sunset. Only IFRAME mode is now supported.  [https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/sandbox-mode?hl=en](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/sandbox-mode?hl=en)